# Is it possible to convert a reference to a std::list<int*> to a reference to a std::list<const int*>?

Tags: c++, stl, constants

Is it  possible to convert a reference to a `std::list<int*>` to a reference to a `std::list<const int*>` ?

A direct static cast fails.

The problem I having is that an object instance maintains a list of int*, and
this list can be returned by reference:

```
std::list<int*>  &A::getList() { return theList; }
```

It would be nice to have a const version of the getList() function which 
looked like:

```
std::list<const int*>  &A::getList() const { return theList; }
```

i.e where the ints are const, and to be able to do this without keeping
two lists.

Comment: The short answer is "No".

Comment: Returning a `const` ref to the list doesn't achieve the ultimate result you want?

Comment: @kfsone that's what I thought for a moment also, but it is not, only the pointers will be `const`, not the data itself. There is a proposal to propagate const to the data, [`propagate_const`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4057.pdf).

Comment: @E_net4 thanks, this question does look like a duplicate of that one

Answer (score 2):

For the compiler, `list<int*>` and `list<const int*>` are two totally unrelated types, same as having `list<Foo>` and `list<Bar>`. Even if `Foo` and `Bar` are related, `list<Foo>` and `list<Bar>` have no relation among themselves whatsoever.

So you need to build you own additional `list<const int*>` from the original `list<int*>` if you want to return it from your `const` function. A direct cast/conversion is not possible.

**EDIT** You may take a look at [`propagate_const`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4057.pdf) wrapper proposal that will allow you to propagate the `const` to the data also. In that case, you'll just define your list with `list<propagate_const<int*>>`, and in your `const` function you can simply return a const reference `const list<propagate_const<int*>>&`. Both the pointers **and** the data they point to will be `const`.

Comment: thanks, i see you have pointed out above, that this would allow the int data to be modified, correct?

Comment: If you just return `const list<int*>&`, unfortunately yes, as only the pointers are `const`, not the data they point to. Hopefully this `propagate_wrapper` will make it to the standard. Or you can write your own, it's not terribly complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

No. It would (implicitly) violate `const` safety.

Adding `const` values through the `const` reference would be modifiable through the non-`const` reference.

Here:

```
std::list<int*> mod;
std::list<const int*>& nomod=magic_cast<std::list<const int*>>(mod);
const int x=19;

nomod.push_back(&x);
(*mod.first())++; //Oh dear!
```

Where `magic_cast` is some operator that does what you're looking for.

Notice that you've implicitly removed const from x.

Comment: @Dam Allen you are quite right, i should have at least written 
const std::list<const int*>  &A::getList() const { return theList; },
but your explanation here makes me think that what i want is not relaistically a valid conversion to ask for

Comment: You have a typo in the first line, must be `std::list<int*> mod;`. However I don't buy this answer, it is basically the same as saying that you can shoot yourself in the foot with accessing `const` data via non-`const` pointers. Of course you can, but you shouldn't. So such a conversion operator must be used with care, but won't violate `const` correct-ness unless the programmer insists. As was said before, C++ protects against Murphy, not Machiavelli.

Comment: @vsoftco At the end of the day somewhere in the template it would be quietly casting off const. That's not helping Murphy. Can Machiavelli write a template that includes `const_cast` that lets you do this without explicit use? Absolutely. Is that something that ought to exist in the STL? Absolutely not.

Comment: @DanAllen Ohhh, I agree that the Standard Library is not probably the best place to have such an cast operator. I thought that you are thinking that even defining it yourself will violate const correctness. It may, it may not, depending how you use it. And it definitely shouldn't be implicit.

Comment: @vsoftco I don't think that was the question. However if you are rolling your own templates and you're putting `const_cast` in the middle of them I think you've probably got even bigger problems than the usual problems a `const_cast` in run-of-the-mill code usually represents. Proceed with extreme caution!